# RenderRepaintBoundary object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: flutter, scaffold

I get this error when I call the closescalenderevent page. I want to display the list I created and if I want to return to the previous page from the back button in the appbar, but I get this error. The screen is not displayed.

[image]
I want to go to the closeseventcalendar page when i click on any day in this calendar and i want to go back to this page from the appbar but i get the error in the title and the page is not displayed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:takvim_app/page/calendar.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' show DateFormat;
import 'package:takvim_app/events/Closespart.dart';
import 'package:takvim_app/Widgets/DropDownmenu.dart';
class CalanderEvent extends StatefulWidget{
  final tarih;

  CalanderEvent(this.tarih);

  @override
  _CalanderEventstate createState() => _CalanderEventstate();

}

class _CalanderEventstate extends State<CalanderEvent> {
  final List<Closespart> tripsList = [
    Closespart(
        "Etkinlik başlığı", DateTime.now(), DateTime.now(), DateTime.now(),
        "Merhaba benim adım name bugun bunu özet yapmak için yaptım ve uzun oldugu zaman aşşağıya inme duurumu olacak diye kontrol ediyorum corona gunlcerınde app geliştme keyfisi Hadi Allaha emanetsın kardeşim"),
    Closespart(
        "Etkinlik başlığı", DateTime.now(), DateTime.now(), DateTime.now(),
        "Özet"),
    Closespart(
        "Etkinlik başlığı", DateTime.now(), DateTime.now(), DateTime.now(),
        "Özet"),
    Closespart(
        "Etkinlik başlığı", DateTime.now(), DateTime.now(), DateTime.now(),
        "Özet"),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: tripsList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
              buildCalendarevent(context, index)),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildCalendarevent(BuildContext context, int index) {
    final trip = tripsList[index];
    String dropdown = "One";
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Detaylar"),
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Calendar()));
              }),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          trip.title,
                          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
                        ),
                        Container(child: DropDown(index))
                      ]),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0, bottom: 16.0),
                    child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "${DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy')
                            .format(trip.Date)
                            .toString()} - ${DateFormat('HH:mm').format(
                            trip.startDate).toString()} - ${DateFormat(
                            'HH:mm')
                            .format(trip.endDate)
                            .toString()}",
                        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                      Spacer()
                    ]),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(trip.summary,
                              maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15.0,
                        ),
                        //Spacer()
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```